# time interval partitioned by 2 fields in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
   id         datetime  interval
0   1  20160101 070000       NaN
1   1  20160101 080000        60
2   1  20160102 070000       NaN
3   1  20160102 073000        30
4   2  20160101 071500       NaN
5   2  20160101 071600         1
```

And would like to generate the interval column - the minutes between rows but only for the same id & the same day, just like in the example - so in sql I would partition by id and datetime and use LAG for the time interval between the previous row. How can I do it in Pandas?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there is an image attached. press on the link "df"

Comment: @Umen: posting an image isn't much help, because then if someone wants to reproduce your frame, they'd have to type in each character one by one.  On the other hand, if you pasted it as text, then people can use `read_clipboard` to reproduce your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert column `datetime` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and  use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and convert `timedelta` to minutes by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print df
   id         datetime  interval
0   1  20160101 070000       NaN
1   1  20160101 080000        60
2   1  20160102 070000       NaN
3   1  20160102 073000        30
4   2  20160101 071500       NaN
5   2  20160101 071600         1

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['new']=df.groupby(['id',df['datetime'].dt.day])['datetime'].diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
print df
   id            datetime  interval  new
0   1 2016-01-01 07:00:00       NaN  NaN
1   1 2016-01-01 08:00:00        60   60
2   1 2016-01-02 07:00:00       NaN  NaN
3   1 2016-01-02 07:30:00        30   30
4   2 2016-01-01 07:15:00       NaN  NaN
5   2 2016-01-01 07:16:00         1    1
```